# TCHAR problem in copy

Tags: visual-c++

Help.

```
TCHAR* b;
TCHAR* c=TEXT("qwerty");
```

I want to allocate memory and copy content of `c` into `b`.

Comment: i want to create vector of all packages installed on the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked in C++ for a while, but from memory the easiest is something like:

```
b = tcscpy(new TCHAR[tcslen(c) + 1], c);
```

The first step allocates the buffer (+1 for an extra TCHAR for the NUL delimiter); the second step copies the entire string into that new buffer; and finally assigns the result (the buffer) to `b`.

Newer versions of the compiler will probably complain about not using the length-limited version of the copy routine (`tcscpy_s` instead of `tcscpy`).

Comment: thx but there is the small problem. i cannon find the headers there that function define.

Comment: The TCHAR macros are defined in `tchar.h`, located in the same folder as the other standard headers like `stdio.h`; use: `#include <tchar.h>`